# Element not displayed in Polymer

Tags: polymer

I'm new to polymer. Below code is not displaying anything. Just a blank page. I'm running this on the default python server. Any idea why this is happening?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"/>
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html"/>
</head>
  <body>
      <hello-element></hello-element>

      <dom-module id="hello-element">
          <template>Hello World</template>
      </dom-module>
      <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady( function () {
        Polymer({
            is: "hello-element"
        })
      })
      </script>
  </body>
</html
```

Comment: This was solved by 2 things. I had to end tags </script> and </link>                                                                   <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"/>
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html"/>

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your closing html tag is malformed. It should be `</html>` instead of `<html`. Perhaps you made a mistake while copying, but you should check just in case.

In addition, your script element should have a closing tag, like so:

```
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
```

Furthermore, the link tag should not have this slash `/` before closing it, like so:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use HTML tags Properly. In HTML5, so-called void elements (elements that can't have content -> link,meta) don't need the closing, but when comes to  tag it must be closing tag. It takes content between  takes as javascript code.

```
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
```

Try to use above format to get correct output. But avoid creating componments in Main document. Create in other file and import it